# How to export my html to pdf and download it?

Tags: php, yii, kartik-v

I searched for topic to how export my html and found no simple solution! Why i have to write tons of codes and download some secondary staff? Here is my div id 'table' and i want to download it as pdf! How i can do it!?

Comment: _"Why i have to write tons of codes"_ - Because no one else will do it for you for free? Not sure what you expect _us_ to do here? Unless you can't just print the page as a PDF (using the browsers print function), you can use a library that makes it easier for you, or will need to write one yourself (which isn't easy).

Comment: `Why i have to write tons of codes and download some secondary staff?` I've just googled for libraries. Most need at most 5 lines for simple tasks. That's *not* tons of codes. And PDF is a complex file format, so you *will* need libraries

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the idea here, but why not open the source code, go to print and do save as PDF?

In chrome you would right click on your page, click on "view page source" then go to print and select save as pdf.